# Skype crackling audio during Test Call?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype

I have a problem with Skype 4.2 during the Test Call that I don't think it matters on client side, but during the test call after the recording and then playback the audio is crackling.

Now I fixed Audacity with the same problem with the package `pulseaudio-module-jack` and the skipping and crackling in my records was gone afterwards.

I have tried these

```
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 5
resample-method = src-sinc-best-quality
```

But it results in no sound from Pulseaudio on reboot, so I have to comment out the first four and reset the resample-method to  speex-float-1.

I did gedit the `PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 to PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30` and still crackling.

And yes, I have removed `tsched=0` from the line `load-module module-udev-detect and load-module module-detect` and still same thing.

Any help is great at this point.

Comment: There is a possible fix for your problem found here.https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50510#c4 I am on my mobile now, if it worked, then I will formally post it as an answer later.

Comment: Well, i am going to upgrade PS from 4.0 to 5.0 to see if that will fix it, but I will post results after my shift at work today.

Comment: Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some googling brought this up:

`Go into the Skype Options menu - Sound Devices - remove the tick at: Allow Skype to automatically adjust my mixer levels. Click Apply. Readjust the sound mixer controls.`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it to a acceptable level, I still hear the crackling but now not as bad.

Comment: @KyleMorehead, if I solved your issue, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Look like I meet same problem. again.

`PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60` and `tsched=0 won't` help.

In google hard and found [advice](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/7l95yk/psa_change_default_shitty_pulseaudio_settings_for/drlgi89/)

Seting in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

```
resample-method = speex-float-10
```

Surprisingly solve problem.

Lover quality resampling, like speex-float-8 don't remove crackling complete.

---

**UPD:**

Later I found above lover crackling but wont eliminate it completly.

Another cause discussed in [Arch wiki related to snd-hda-intel module](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Glitches.2C_skips_or_crackling), in my case ALC887, force me search for snd-hda-intel parameters.
And found solution [bdl_pos_adj: set IRQ timing workaround for hda-intel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203792/bdl-pos-adj-set-irq-timing-workaround-for-hda-intel)

Crackling fixed by applying module parameters in /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf

`options snd_hda_intel vid=8086 pid=1e20 bdl_pos_adj=16,16`

- vid=8086 pid=1e20 is PCI id of my audio device Realtek® ALC887
- bdl_pos_adj value choosen by experiment

  - bdl_pos_adj=2,2 keep crackling
  - bdl_pos_adj=1,48 make ugly skips
  - bdl_pos_adj=16,16 sounds acceptable

**UPD2:**

Now I changed to `bdl_pos_adj=-1,32`

There first number os device number and -1 mean all

*I think, in future, avoid using ALC887 as it cracling not only in skype but also in Adacity.*